# Why every time when I run a spark code in Python I have those warnings

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

When I run a spark code in python from my Pycharm IDE I have the same warning text.

```
'WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/C:/Spark/Spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.3.jar) to method java.nio.Bits.unaligned()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
19/08/26 16:47:14 WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.'
```

Comment: `mssql_df.createOrReplaceTempView("Data")
spark.sql("select timestamp, `Project Id` from Data").count()`


Also, I have this problem:

`pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 56'`